# Query on Process builder Scheduled Actions

Tags: apex, soql, process-builder

We have 100+ scheduled Process builders that triggers based on conditions. As a end user We want to show which process builder Actions scheduled related with Lead/Contact object as creating child object of Lead/Contact.

I did SOQL query on "FlowInterview" but this does not any relationship with contact/Lead record Id.

Can any one please suggest workaround on this.

Answer (score -2):

Try SOQL on [`FlowRecordRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_flowrecordrelation.htm) - the `ParentId` and the `RelatedRecordId` are a junction between the FlowInterview and the SObject, respectively

Comment: Brian, FlowRecordRelation is not returning records in SOQL Query even Process builder actions scheduled.

Comment: Are you sure you have Flows in the schedule?  If you look through the scheduled Flows via Setup, you can confirm items are in the queue?

Comment: It seems that records for this object are created when you explicitly set {!$Flow.CurrentRecord} in a Flow. This will then be used to display the new Paused Flow Interviews component in the app builder.